# iCal in Google Calendar; rrule: every other weekday

Tags: icalendar, weekday, rrule

My wife (teacher) teaches every other *weekday*.  Is it possible to make a recurrence rule that covers that?  I tried:

```
    RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=5;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR,TU,TH
```

...but that didn't work.  It just did every day, every other week.

Comment: ...or alternately, what _is_ the way to accomplish this? Is the only way to do more than one file? @#$%^&*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your wife's requirement, you want to use a daily rrule, with interval 2 (the order of they BYDAY does not matter):

```
FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
```

Comment: now I feel ridiculous, of course; but the (right) answer is moot, because the actual schedule isn't strict about the pattern; thanks, and sorry